# Documentation for .vsif File

Tags: scripting, verification

Is there a documentation for the syntax of vsif files (verification session input format)? I couldn't find anything although I already googled for a couple of hours. I'm using SystemVerilog and Cadence xrun.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cadence documentation is either online at https://support.cadence.com (requires account) or can be accessed with the `cdnshelp` command.

The annoying thing is that Cadence uses `cdnshelp` as an executable in each of their software packages. If you have both Xcelium and vManager installed, `cdnshelp` will point to either the documentation for one or the other, depending on what order you have them in `PATH`. To work around this, call the executable directly (`/path/to/vmanager/install/bin/cdnshelp`). You can get this path by doing a `which -a cdnshelp`, which will list you all executables called `cdnshelp` that you have in `PATH`.